# Finding All Multipler Results in Single SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, hierarchical-data

I have a table in below

```
Sub1   Sub2   Total
 1     2       300
 1     3       200
 2     1       600
```

And I need a sql query for results below

```
 1     0       500
 1     2       300
 1     3       200
 2     0       600
 2     1       600
```

Any help pls ? I need a single query without union if its possible?

Answer (score 2):

Using `ROLLUP`:

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT
        Sub1, 
        Sub2 = ISNULL(Sub2, 0),
        Total = SUM(Total)
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY ROLLUP(Sub1, Sub2)
)t
WHERE Sub1 IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Sub1, Sub2
```

---

Using `SUM` and `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
UNION ALL
SELECT Sub1, 0, SUM(Total)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Sub1
ORDER BY Sub1, Sub2
```

Comment: NO POSSİBLE WİTHOUT UNİON OR UNİON ALL?

Comment: Try searching for `ROLLUP` or `GROUPING SETS`.